# Scheme matching elements

Tags: list, lisp, scheme

I'm currently playing a bit around with scheme, and I've been stuck for quite a while trying to figure out how to implement a test, that checks if any element in 'xs' is also stored in 'l'.

That is the mathematical function '\in', just for each element in the list xs.

Comment: Writing a recursive defintion, however all I'm getting is errors, and I'm quite fed up with it right now -.-

Comment: Yea sorry, but went somewhat along the lines of Ross Larsons, solution now that I came to check it. So obviously he got the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to write it yourself for practice, or do you just need the functionality?

If you just want the functionality then use the answer by larsmans (I have never used that, but it looks good to me).

To implement try the following (disclaimer: I have not tested this)

```
(define has-intersect?
      (lambda (xs l)
           (cond
             [(null? xs) #f]
             [(member? (car xs) l) #t]
             [else (has-intersect? (cdr xs) l)])))
```

Answer (score 1):

In mathematical terms, you're checking whether the intersection of two lists/sets is non-empty. If you have an [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#lset-intersection) library, this is trivial:

```
(not (null? (lset-intersection l xs)))
```

An implementation of SRFI-1 can be found in [SLIB](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jaffer/SLIB.html).

(Disclaimer: I'm a former SLIB contributor.)